# User defined form, wpf binding controls position

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm trying to let the user to design his own form and save the controls positions into a DB.
Right now I was able to allow the user to spawn new controls and move them around the form. What I dont know is how to get the position of the controls to my Datacontext. I was able to only bind the width etd...

I was hoping I could bind the canvas.left & canvas.top to datacontext but those are not updated on the renderTransform.

Any Ideas?Thanks for help.

Heres the form back code for moving the controls:

```
        private Control _currentlyDragged;

        private Point _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset;

        private void Window_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_currentlyDragged != null)
            {
                var mousePos = e.GetPosition(this);
                var futurePos = e.GetPosition(BuildCanvas);

                if (futurePos.X <= 0 || futurePos.Y <= 0 || futurePos.Y >= BuildCanvas.ActualHeight || futurePos.X >= BuildCanvas.ActualWidth)
                    return;

                _currentlyDragged.RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform(mousePos.X - _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset.X, mousePos.Y - _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset.Y);
            }
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_currentlyDragged != null)
                _currentlyDragged = null;

            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        private void Window_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            Point pt = e.GetPosition((UIElement)sender);
            _hitResultsList.Clear();

            VisualTreeHelper.HitTest(this, null, new HitTestResultCallback(MyHitTestResult), new PointHitTestParameters(pt));

            if (!_hitResultsList.Where(h => h is Border && ((Border)h).Name == "BuildCanvas").Any())
                return;

            if (_hitResultsList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (DependencyObject d in _hitResultsList)
                {
                    var parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(d);

                    if (parent != null && (parent is Label || parent is TextBox))
                    {
                        CaptureMouse();

                        _currentlyDragged = parent as Control;

                        if (_currentlyDragged.RenderTransform is TranslateTransform)
                        {
                            _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset.X = e.GetPosition(this).X - ((TranslateTransform)_currentlyDragged.RenderTransform).X;
                            _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset.Y = e.GetPosition(this).Y - ((TranslateTransform)_currentlyDragged.RenderTransform).Y;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset.X = pt.X;
                            _currentlyDraggedMouseOffset.Y = pt.Y;
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            _currentlyDragged = null;
        }

        private HitTestResultBehavior MyHitTestResult(HitTestResult result)
        {
            _hitResultsList.Add(result.VisualHit);
            return HitTestResultBehavior.Continue;
        }
```

Heres the ItemsControl:

```
    <Border x:Name="BuildCanvas" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Background="#fff4c9" CornerRadius="10">
        <Grid>
            <!-- Generated controls -->
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding TextBoxCollection}" Panel.ZIndex="1">

                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Canvas/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Padding="2" IsEnabled="False" Background="White"
                                 Text="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}" Width="{Binding Width}">
                        </TextBox>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
            <!-- -->
        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

Comment: I think rendertransform is only useful as a way to display the dragging effect while it happens. When the dragging finished, you should probably update the resulting position in a different way (layout-transform or re-positioning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rendertransform is a bad idea. Each textbox is in a container.

You should bind the Canvas.Top and Canvas.Left of the itemcontainer. Something like:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style>
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding XviewModelProperty}" />
        <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding YviewModelProperty}" />
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Cast the datacontext of your textbox to whatever your viewmodel type is and set XviewModelProperty and YviewModelProperty.

Ensure they raise property changed when set.

Comment: But how will the user move the control without the rendertransform?

Comment: When they drag, you set X and Y which sets the  canvas.Left and Canvas.Top of the container the textbox is in. Which moves the control.

Comment: I dont get it... How do I set XviewModelProperty from the back code on the Window_PreviewMouseMove? I mean....controls are added by adding items into TextBoxCollection - ObservableCollection inside ViewModel for the form.

Comment: You have a reference to the textbox. It's datacontext is textboxviewmodel or whatever type Textboxcollection is full of. Cast the datacontext of the control and you have it's viewmodel. That viewmodel has an X property or whatever. Essentially, set it to the x location of the mouse modified by the offset from the left side of the textbox when they pressed the button down. Because they are unlikely to have "clicked" the top left corner of your control. Don't try and work out the difference to last move because your control won't keep up if you do that.

Comment: Thanks, accesing the datacontext and changing the property worked like a charm!